# Как автоматически вставить дату (ДДММГГГГ) и при пересчёте (на следующий день) она не менялась

Tags: дата, google-docs

Как сделать что бы при внесении данных в Google docs, в ячейку A1:1000, в ячейке B1:1000 автоматически проставлялась дата и она при пересчёте (на следующий день) не изменялась

Comment: *и она при пересчёте (на следующий день) не изменялась* А при изменении данных в А1:А1000 дата должна меняться или нет?

Comment: Нет, не должна меняться

Comment: Тогда пишите обработчик OnChange, который при непустом INTERSECT(Target, Range("A1:A1000")) пройдёт по пересечению, для каждой непустой ячейки проверит cell.offset(0,1).Tag, и, если он пуст, то запишет в ячейку и в тег текущую дату.

Comment: Akina спасибо, но я в этом не понимаю, я думал может есть какое то готовое решение